# How to get around encrypted hard drive

Tags: boot, disk-encryption

I had a full volume encryption on my fedora work station but forgot my password. I figured the only way to get around this is to wipe the drive. Well I can’t because every time I change the boot order in BIOS it resets the boot order to default. I’m trying to install fedora 31 via usb and I’m stuck here. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: To answer this, we will need to know more about what device you are using. The firmware is not the same in all, so we can't give a generic way to set the boot order. Also the body of your question is about booting, and the title is about encryption.

Comment: Full crystal ball mode: if your BIOS is keyboard-driven, it might be set to US keyboard layout, and the `y` for "do you want to save" might not be where you think it is. Can you successfully set any other attributes in BIOS? Also, there might be a way during startup to select the boot device, that depends on the make of BIOS/firmware.

Comment: From what media are you going to intall "Fedora 31"? It should have a disk partitioning section...

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar boot issues after using GNU shred on hard disks and SSDs.  In this case, I think the boot sector data is 'corrupted' by the random data.

My workaround was to shutdown the computer and disconnect the SATA data cable of the hard disk / SSD.  Power on the computer, and boot to Linux from the USB flash drive.  Reconnect the SATA data cable of the hard disk / SSD, determine the device designation of the SATA hard disk / SSD, and secure erase / test / zero it:

```
sudo lsblk -a -fs

#NOTE:  In the following command, change "sdX" to the device to be erased and tested, and be prepared to wait a few hours:

sudo bash -c 'device=sdX && time shred -n1 /dev/$device && time badblocks -wvs /dev/$device && time blkdiscard -v /dev/$device ; date -Iseconds'
```